# Как корректно задать начальное состояние React-компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Делаю небольшое приложение на React. Проблема с заданием начального состояния. Привожу код редьюсера.

```
 const iniState = { 
   currencyReducer : { date : new Date, currencies : [] }
 };

 export const currencyReducer = (state = iniState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'REFRESH_DATE':
     return Object.assign({}, { date : action.date, currencies :   action.currencies} );
default:
  return state;
 }
 };
```

Вот код компонента.

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
   return { date : state.currencyReducer.date, 
        currencies : state.currencyReducer.currencies } };


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return { 
    refreshDate : bindActionCreators(refreshDate, dispatch)
 }}

class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div className="content">
    <h3>Котировки валют</h3>
    <p>
    <input type="date"  ref='date_' />
    <button onClick={this.onRefreshDate.bind(this) } > Выбрать </button>
    </p>
    {this.props.currencies.map((item,i) => <p> { item.name}  </p>)}
  </div>
)
}

onRefreshDate() {
let date_ = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.date_).value;
this.props.refreshDate(date_, this.props.currencies);
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Content);
```

При старте приложения выдается в консоли

```
bundle.js:23598 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Что сделано не так?

Comment: пробовали дебажить функцию `onRefreshDate`? Мне кажется проблема в ней, т.к. не совсем ясно какой контекс вы хотите в ней получить

Answer (score 0):

Решилась проблема очень просто - продебажили, как формируется стейт и написали вот так соответствие свойства компонента-стейт:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => { 
  return { date : state.currencyReducer.date, 
           currencies : state.currencyReducer.currencies } };
```

Так все заработало, исключение ушло.